# Polymer Service Worker Not Caching

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, service-worker

I have this custom element which fetches the facebook profile pic(very small size) with url. I am using a service worker to intercept the call out and cache it. However, it does not seem to effective. The call out goes out over network with every page refresh. In addition, there is nothing in dev tools under local storage. I also tried `cacheOnly` and it still called out to the network for the url, so I know that the service worker `platinum-sw-fetch` is not effective.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? If it did work, shouldn't I see something in local storage for dev tools? I do see the service worker itself in dev tools though.

```
<platinum-sw-register auto-register
                      clients-claim
                      skip-waiting
                      base-uri="../bower_components/platinum-sw/bootstrap">
  <platinum-sw-fetch
    origin="https://z-1-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net"
    path="/hprofile(.*)"
    handler="cacheFirst">
  </platinum-sw-fetch>
</platinum-sw-register>
```

Comment: I think you are talking about **<platinum-sw-cache></platinum-sw-cache>** component.

Comment: No, that element is when you want to cache *everything* instead of a single url. It's a convenience wrapper to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Polymer (or `platinum-sw`) issue, it's due to the way Service Workers function.

A service worker only serves fetch requests for its own *scope*: specifically, on the same domain as the service worker file, and in that directory or lower. So if you register it using a sw file at:

https://example.com/stuff/service-worker.js

It will only intercept fetch requests that start with https://example.com/stuff/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/#toc-before

(See the section, How to Register and Install a Service Worker.)

If you want to do something like this, you'd need to proxy the requests through your own server.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `platinum-sw` has a `origin` attribute for 
` "If you'd like to define a custom handler for requests on a specific cross-origin domain, you must use the origin parameter in conjunction with path to match the domains you'd like to handle." `
 From https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/platinum-sw?active=platinum-sw-fetch

Comment: Sorry, I missed understood. Tried to switch the upvote. What about `origin` attribute for a separate domain?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're correct and I jumped the gun here. You should be able to fetch some cross-domain resources. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Can you tell if the SW is booting up? Double check the actual fetched path against your regexps? Seeing any errors in console?

Comment: The only error is `ERR_FILE_EXISTS` which isn't related..... it's just noise from https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541797. Yes, SW is booting up.... I see the worker in dev tools. Just to confirm, the `platinum-sw` elements do cache images, correct?